# Transform HTML to JSF

Tags: html, jsf

I hava an unordered List navigation and i wanted to transform this to JSF code.
Actually , there is no  JSF tag ..

Here is the raw-HTML Navigation :

```
<ul id="navbar">
<li id="articles"><a href="Link1">Articles</a></li>
<li id="topics"><a href="Link2" title="Topics">Topics</a></li>
....
</ul>
```

..so what should i do ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do ad-hoc templating is to use [Facelets](https://facelets.dev.java.net/) instead of JSPs. Since these have become part of JSF 2.0 (due in JEE6), I think it is a good time to consider them.

For example, for the beans:

```
public class LiBean implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  private String href;
  private String title;

  public String getHref() { return href; }

  public void setHref(String href) { this.href = href; }

  public String getTitle() { return title; }

  public void setTitle(String title) { this.title = title; }

}
```

...and:

```
public class UlBean implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  private final List<LiBean> listItems = new ArrayList<LiBean>();

  public UlBean() {
    String[] links = { "http://www.sun.com", "Sun",
        "http://www.oracle.com", "Oracle",
        "http://www.ibm.com", "IBM",
        "http://stackoverflow.com",
        "<stackoverflow.com> & encoded output" };
    for (int i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
      LiBean item = new LiBean();
      item.setHref(links[i]);
      item.setTitle(links[++i]);
      listItems.add(item);
    }
  }

  public List<LiBean> getListItems() {
    return listItems;
  }

}
```

...defined in session scope:

```
  <managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>ulBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>beans.UlBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
  </managed-bean>
```

...can be used in this Facelet page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>repeat</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
  <ui:repeat value="#{ulBean.listItems}" var="item">
    <li><a href="#{item.href}"><h:outputText
      value="#{item.title}" /></a></li>
  </ui:repeat>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

...to produce this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" >
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>repeat</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
    <li><a href="http://www.sun.com">Sun</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.oracle.com">Oracle</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.ibm.com">IBM</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com">&lt;stackoverflow.com&gt; &amp; encoded output</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

---

If you are sticking with JSPs, there isn't anything in the core implementation that will let you do this (the only repeating control is the *dataTable*). You may find something in one of the [3rd party component libraries](http://www.jsfmatrix.net/).

Comment: Maybe worth adding that Facelets has no issue with mixing JSF components and standard HTML (no need for f:verbatim). You can just add the list items as they are if you want.

Comment: Well, you have to be careful about that. JSF does have issues when mixing HTML tags with JSF tags when it comes to Ajax calls. We've experienced a lot of issues with that in the past.